# How to obtain start and commit timestamps of transactions?

Tags: python, transactions, dgraph

How can I obtain start and commit timestamps of transactions in Dgraph from operation messages or database logs? I need to issue multiple transactions in each client session.

I use [this Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/dgraph/dgraph):

```
docker pull dgraph/dgraph:latest # version:v23.1.0
```

And pydgraph-23.0.1 driver with Python v3.8.18. I use [simple.py](https://github.com/dgraph-io/pydgraph/blob/master/examples/simple/simple.py) and changed `localhost` on line 10 to `175.27.241.31`. `175.27.241.31` is publicly available (you can use it directly without pulling the Docker image). I added `print(response)` after line 78 but there is only `start_ts` for the transaction. I do not find `commit_ts`:

```
txn {
  start_ts: 260380056
  keys: ...
    ...
    preds: ...
    ...
}
latency {
    ...
}
metrics {
    ...
}
uids {
    ...
}
```

- How to obtain `commit_ts` for transactions using pydgraph? Is there any official documentation or source code for this?
- Does following code from simple.py mean client is issuing multiple transactions *one by one*?
- Are there other ways of obtaining start and commit timestamps than using pydgraph? Code examples are appreciated.

```py
def main():
    client_stub = create_client_stub()
    client = create_client(client_stub)
    drop_all(client)
    set_schema(client)
    create_data(client)
    query_alice(client)  # query for Alice
    query_bob(client)  # query for Bob
    delete_data(client)  # delete Bob
    query_alice(client)  # query for Alice
    query_bob(client)  # query for Bob

    # Close the client stub.
    client_stub.close()
```

[Related](https://discuss.dgraph.io/t/how-to-obtain-the-start-and-commit-timestamps-of-transactions-of-dgraph-using-pydgraph/18964?u=hengxin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from [Ruohao Zhang @ discuss.dgraph.io](https://discuss.dgraph.io/t/how-to-obtain-the-start-and-commit-timestamps-of-transactions-of-dgraph-using-pydgraph/18964/2?u=hengxin):

I want to get the `commit_ts` by using pydgraph. However, the function `commit()` doesn't return the commit_ts. By modifying line 238 in `txn.py`, I return the result of the function `self._dc.commit_or_abort`.

```
return self._dc.commit_or_abort(self._ctx, timeout=timeout,
                                     metadata=new_metadata,
                                     credentials=credentials)
```

Like this, I could get the `commit_ts` from the function `commit()`.

The result is following:
start_ts: 260380200
commit_ts: 260380201

---

I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/dgraph-io/pydgraph/issues/212) on github.

Updated: The corresponding [PR has been accepted](https://github.com/dgraph-io/pydgraph/pull/213).